# Convertir de string a binario en swift

Tags: binario

estoy utilizando este método para convertir de string a binario

```
 let a = "1"

    let binay = Data(a.utf8)

    let byte = binay.reduce("") { (acc, byte) -> String in
        acc + String(byte, radix: 2)
    }

    print(byte)
```

cuando imprimo byte la respuesta es correcta ya comprobé manualmente con la tabla assci sin embargo está imprimiendo sin el primer cero adelante. A alguien le ha pasado ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma correcta para realizar la conversión de un String a Binario es la siguiente:

```
let string = "1"
let aBinaryData = Data(string.utf8)

let resultado = aBinaryData.reduce("") { (acc, byte) -> String in
    acc + String(byte, radix: 2)
}

print(resultado)
```

teniendo como salida:

```
110001
```

la representación binaria de la cadena "1" en realidad ocupa 2 Bytes por lo que se sobre entiende que tendría 2 ceros al inicio :

```
00110001
```

Comment: Claro pero yo quiero los bit completos, no quiero concatenar los 0 faltantes.